# webdriver findelement by xpath <a> <span> C#

Tags: c#, xpath, hyperlink, webdriver

I need to create a test in webdriver with C# where I click a link with the "Text" in menu which has structure like this:

```
<ul style="overflow: hidden">
    <li>
        <ul class"menu" style="overflow: hidden">
            <li class="class_li">
                <a href="/level1/leve2">
                    <span class="class_span">Text</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
    <li />
    <li />
</ul>
```

classes ""class_li" and "class_span" are used many times. I cannot modify the html code.

I tried few different xpath statements but everytime I got "InvalidSelectorException was unhandled". How can I get to my link and click it?

Comment: Is the text visible in the webpage at all times or do you have to click on some link to get to it ?

Comment: I need to hover the menu then it slides from the side, next I need to hover menu position and then "sub-menu" with my link slides out.

Comment: Please add more of the HTML snippet then, starting from the `main menu` to the item in the `sub-menu` you want to click or the code snippet you've worked upon so far to employ the same feat. Also, if you can provide a snapshot of how your menu looks like, that will be helpful too.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I made it. I used Actions and XPath based on StuartLC answer, it looks something like this:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[span/text()='text_from_upper_node']"));
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.MoveToElement(element).Build().Perform();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[span/text()='text_from_link_I_want_to_click']")).Click();
```

Thank you for help. cheers

Answer (score 0):

The following xpath with select the first `a` link which has a direct child `span` with the text `Text`

```
(//a[span/text()='Text'])[1]
```

I'm no Selenium expert, but you should be able to do this:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("(//a[span/text()='Text'])[1]")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always try something like this if there are multiple trees that you may want to use?

```
        IList<IWebElement> webElements = WebDriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("class_span"));
```

you can then just enumerate over the list to click what you want, or even something like the following:

```
        var text = webElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Text == "Text");
        text.Click();
```